# What code is needed to be notified in real-time whenever my iOS app is downloaded?

Tags: ios

I recently published my first iOS app and felt really dissatisfied with apple's iTunesConnect portal for tracking app sales. Specifically, I can't tell what time of day the app was downloaded, and I have to wait for the results until the next morning.

Does anyone know a piece of code that can be unobstrusively inserted in my app that will somehow report to me after if has been installed for the first time? I don't want any privacy/rules violations, I just want the app to report that it has been downloaded, and maybe a few metrics regarding country/time/etc.

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:

Regarding a first run 'phone home,' is it possible to execute some HTML without having the user knowing (I don't want to interrupt their experience by opening a webbrowser). For example, some javascript from a statcounter? If not, what can I do?

Comment: nope, but you can certainly do a first-run phone-home.

Comment: I can setup a code execution on first run, but how do you do the phone-home part?

Comment: The search term you're looking for is `analytics`

Comment: Thanks - So how do I phone home on first run with said analytics?

Comment: Why do you need this information?  Will it make a difference?

Comment: You could send a JSON encoded message back to your web server or just do a POST request to a form on a web page

Comment: Just store information as a flag in - for example - userDefaults

Comment: @BlueConga: Well, he's still not going to get it out of the app then

Comment: below link may be helpful for you (Google Analytics for iOS)
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/

Comment: [Tapstream](https://tapstream.com/) can do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of analytics tools that can help you get better metrics.

Flurry
Google Analytics
Mixpanel
Kissmetrics

Google analytics gives you usage information in real time, which is nice.

Also, if your users log in through Facebook, they provide some interesting analytics as well.

Comment: Didn't know Google Analytics offered an iOS flavor, thanks for the tip

Comment: Google analytics is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Yep! I've been using it for a few weeks. It's very nice, actually.